# How can I split a large column of data into multiple columns of data in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, multiple-columns

I have a large column of data (400,000+ data points) being imported from a text file. I need the column to be divided into multiple columns of length 7,000. It is already in order, so the first 7,000 data points would stay in the first column, the next 7,000 would go to the next column, and so forth...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reshape the data into a 2D matrix, but all columns must be the same length (7,000).

You can either select only complete columns:

```
x = rand(1,400000);    
N = 7000;
cols = floor(length(x)/N);
y = reshape(x(1:N*cols), [N,cols]);
```

Alternatively, you can pad the final column (eg with zeros):

```
x = rand(1,400000);    
N = 7000;
cols = ceil(length(x)/N);
y = zeros(N, cols);
y(1:length(x)) = x;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `buffer` command:

```
x = rand(400000,1);
[out,z]=buffer(x,7000);
```

Here `out` corresponds to the 2D matrix with `7000` elements in each column. If the length of the vector is not divisible by `7000`, the last column of data which has length less than `7000` is stored in `z`.

Comment: Minor note: You need the signal processing toolbox to use this method.  `reshape` is native to MATLAB.

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks alot, I shall make note of it.

Comment: No problem.  Still gave you +1 anyway as it's a good method to use.

Answer (score 1):

Using reshape function can do this

```
A = reshape(B,7000,[]);
```

Comment: You have chosen to write your own answer.  As such, either accept your own answer to signify the SO community that you no longer need help, or accept one of the answers above.

Comment: Per SO rules, you must wait 48 hours from the time you originally asked your question before you can accept your own answer. So simmer down rayryeng, I will get to it when the time comes

Comment: Sorry, I forgot there was a 48 hour limit. Not sure why you told me to simmer down as I wasn't angry. Just want to make sure that people know this question is solved. On the other hand, you could go ahead and accept any of the other answers to give them some rep points :) You don't get anything by accepting your own answer.